# Loading lots of Text (spannablestring) into Android textview taking 200ms plus?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview, lazy-loading, spannablestring

I'm currently developing a Bible in Android which is Paragraph based so a ListView won't work. I implemented a ViewPager using fragments for each new chapter that is loaded. The problem I'm having is that when I set the TextView text (mytextview.settext()), it takes over 200 ms just to display one chapter. Please note that the Text I'm loading into the TextView is a SpannableString with data for Red letters, Verses, Etc. For scrolling the TextView is encapsulated in a ScrollView for smooth scrolling. Any ideas on how to implement a lazy loading system in a TextView or how to speed up the process of displaying the text? Any answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you said it wouldn't work, I would suggest using a `ListView` with a custom `Adapter` (or `RecyclerView` for the latest API) to handle this instead of a single `TextView`. A `ListView` with a custom `Adapter` will be a more efficient way of managing tons of text as long as you follow the "ViewHolder" pattern in your `Adapter`. Every paragraph in your chapter can be a separate list item which will be recycled when the user scrolls a paragraph off screen. There are tons of tutorials on the internet concerning custom `ListView` `Adapters` in Android so I will not repeat them here; however, I hope this post can point you in the right direction.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Not all paragraphs are verses. I might try what you suggested above as it would clearly be the fastest option. Thanks for your thoughtful reply!

Comment: No problem Seth! I've actually used this method in one of my applications. If you need to see a working example, check out my Adapter:

https://github.com/JohnPersano/CrimeTalk-Reader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/org/crimetalk/adapters/ArticleContentAdapter.java

And the Fragment which uses it:

https://github.com/JohnPersano/CrimeTalk-Reader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/org/crimetalk/fragments/ArticleContentFragment.java

Note: I need to download information from a webpage to get the data in the Fragment so a lot of that code won't apply to your project.